# Get ACAccount after login with Twitter SDK from Fabric Swift

Tags: twitter, swift2, twitter-fabric, acaccount

I need a way to get `ACAccount` which is created, or taken by `Twitter SDK` provided by `Fabric` while login with:

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().logInWithCompletion { (session: TWTRSession?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let userSession = session {
    }
    else {
    } 
}
```

I need this account, to use while posting in background with `SLRequest`. Without `account` is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already using Twitter SDK, no need to deal with ACAccount anymore.

Just follow their instructions, and you can build a request manually: 
[Build TW Request manually](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/access-rest-api.html#constructing-a-twitter-request-manually)

Here is that code updated for Swift 2:

```
if let userID = Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session()?.userID {
    let client = TWTRAPIClient(userID: userID)

    let statusesShowEndpoint    = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"
    var clientError : NSError?

    let request                 = client.URLRequestWithMethod("POST", URL: statusesShowEndpoint, parameters: dictMessage, error: &clientError)

    if let err = clientError {
        print("Error: \(err)")
    }
    else {
        client.sendTwitterRequest(request) { (response, data, connectionError) -> Void in
            if (connectionError == nil) {
                do {
                    if let dictTWData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        print("\(dictTWData)")
                    }
                }
                catch _ as NSError {

                }
                catch {
                   fatalError()
                }
            }
            else {
                print("Error: \(connectionError)")
            }
         }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Perfect solution!  Thanks

Comment: But, I wanted to use the Swifter Twitter library because it makes handling of the rest APIs more bearable. However Swifter needs ACAccount to initialize the Swifter object. How would one go about creating an ACAccount object using Twitter sharedInstance session? Seems, even though Twitter documents say that iOS 11 doesn't support Social Framework for iOS but my tests shows that it still does support without any issues (not sure how or why).